# How to change the behaviour of back button in Android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

The action of back button is bring back to the previous page.

How to change the action of back button in Android fragment, for example:

```
if( click back button ) then 
Toast.maketext("text");
```

my code is  :

```
public class Rechercher extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* pour creer le fragment */
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rechercheavance, container, false);    
        return view;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Activity`, override the `onBackPressed()` method for custom back press action. Hold an instance of the fragment when you attach it and use a public method in the fragment for doing something from the fragment by calling it from the `onBackPressed()` method.

**Activity**

```
SomeFragment fragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    //Create the fragment instance
    fragment = new SomeFragment();
    //Now add the fragment to the layout
}

...

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Called when back pressed
    fragment.doSomething();
}
```

And in the **Fragment** define the method `doSomething`

```
public void doSomething() {
    //custom action
}
```

Comment: in fragment     ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?

Comment: Not possible. If you have to, then define a public method inside the fragment and call it from inside the onBackPressed method from the activity.

Comment: Edited my answer as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: No , it's is probleme

Comment: Are you changing your fragments? If so, then it will create problems. You need the active instance of the fragment to call the method

Comment: This is a bad solution, because on every `Activity` recreate it also adds a `Fragment`, but it already exists in `FragmentManager`. Also your `Activity` is strongly bound with the `Fragment` and cannot change its behaviour. A better solution is to define `interface OnBackPressedListener` and override its method in needed fragments, then change `onBackPressed` in the `Activity`. See topics on this.